# M1 macbook pro randomly outputs garbage audio when closed / sleep

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a 2021 m1 mbp...  I keep it plugged into external speakers, and at random moments (like just now it happened twice within a 10 minute period) it will just output horrific loud garbage noise for 1/4 a second and then stop.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: How do you have your speakers connected? Analog 1/8" connection? Digital optical connection? HDMI? Are they connected via an amplifier?

Comment: If they have a built-in power amp, then you're hearing the Mac's internal amps shut down at power-loss, making random power-spikes. You will have to mitigate this at the amp. [I have pro studio speakers here with 400w of power, 2ft from my head… you learn pretty quickly to never let the Mac sleep or reboot when they're switched on. It's like being kicked in the face by a rhino in big studded boots ;)

Comment: It could just be loose wiring on the cables, of course.

Comment: @benwiggy umm.. no.

Comment: @agarza yes, 1/8" wire directly to an amp.

Comment: If the speakers can be connected directly to the MBP, try that first. It could be the amp. If the speakers need to be amplified, then try another set of speakers that don't need an amp or a set of headphones. You need to isolate where the problem lies.

Comment: @agarza It's not the amp.. It's the MBP outputting garbage randomly.

Comment: How have you determined that the amp is not the problem?

Comment: @agarza because this only happens when the mbp is either sleeping or booting up, NEVER when the mac is in booted and in active use.  There are 4-5 horrific audio spikes each and every time OS X is booting.

Comment: @patrick Help me, help you. Components need to be isolated to figure out which one is actually causing the problem. Just because you think one component "could never be the problem", it usually ends up being the problem. (personal experience)

Comment: Turn the main amp down/off. There's nothing you're going to do about the thump/random buffer data an op amp wired directly to a DAC makes when it's power-cycled. You can't turn it down at that point, it's not yet initialised. That output was never designed to be run into an amp, so the noise suppression normally built-into a power amp at power-cycle [that 2-second wait between powering the amp & hearing the speakers actually switch on] just isn't in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an issue with the 2021 M1 MacBook Pro having audio problems. An article on 9to5Mac.com mentions "multiple complaints" on the [Apple Communicty forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253531295) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookpro/comments/s4r1m5/macbook_pro_16_2021_audio_crackling_issue_m1_pro/).

The article does happen to mention a possible solution:

> A Reddit user corroborated this theory by saying that the problems can be temporarily fixed after killing the macOS process “coreaudiod” by going to the Activity Monitor app. Some users claim that the issues disappeared after installing macOS 12.3, but other users are still experiencing crackling speakers.

In the comments for the article, several users have mentioned other solutions that worked for them, but they are different for each person.